# How to use Repository and Unit of Work Patterns with ADO.NET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, ado.net, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I am building ASP.NET MVC 5 application.

I read about Repository and Unit of Work (UoW) Patterns [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

These examples use Entity Framework which adds a high-level of abstraction itself.

I am using ADO.NET and not EF. I want to know:

1. Whether Repository and UoW patterns makes any sense with ADO.NET?
2. How will my Repositories and UoW look with ADO.NET? Any Samples?
3. Can I add a separate class library for Repository or to make it a part of DAL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've written a [blog post](http://blog.gauffin.org/2013/01/ado-net-the-right-way/) which teaches you on how to write driver independent code and how to implement Uow/Repository pattern with plain ADO.NET.

It's a bit too long to include in this answer, but basically the `IDbtransaction` will represent your Unit oF Work (or be contained in one) and every repository will take the transaction or UoW in it's constructor.

To create a command using a `IDbTransaction`

```
using (var cmd = transaction.Connection.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.Transaction = transaction;

    //do a CRUD operation here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, but how would you go about using a DI container (ninject for example) for the repositories, and for the factory too for that matter in say a WebApi/MVC project? as the repo's need their uow instance to be instantiated

Comment: `yourContainer.RegisterService<IDbTransaction>(container => container.Resolve<IDbConnection>().BeginTransaction());`

Comment: @jgauffin I read [this post of yours](http://blog.gauffin.org/2014/01/unit-of-work-sample-implementation-for-ado-net/)  And I got a couple of questions: 1) Is there any performance penalty for creating a transaction even when you're only reading (select) data? 2) What are the implementations details of IUnitOfWork? Could you show us the code for it? Thanks.

Comment: Dead link, anyone knows working link of the article?

Comment: @MehdiDehghani you can use the WayBackMachine: https://web.archive.org/web/20190324105115/http://blog.gauffin.org/2013/01/ado-net-the-right-way/

Answer (score 1):

1. The Unit of Work pattern is more important when you're talking about standard ADO.NET because you have to make absolutely sure that the connections you're opening are only open for the required period of time, achieved by wrapping connections inside `using` statements.
2. Unit of Work in ADO.NET would look something like this:

`using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(//connection string)
{
     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(storedProcname, con))
     {
        //...
     }
}`

As you're using `using` statements to encompass your unit of work, you can be assured that under the hood `SqlConnection.Dispose()` calls the `SqlConnection.Close()` method, and `SqlCommand.Dispose()` calls `SqlCommand.Close()`.

3. As answered in your previous question, you can separate these two out if you wish to do so, but personally I think they should be the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [definitions](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/) of the patterns, and the patterns required to support them, you'll see that, if you start to implement them yourself, you'll never be wandering far from creating your own ORM. While this is a fascinating task, it's never worth it when you consider NHibernate and EntityFramework.

However, to answer your question, I found Fowler's [PoEAA](http://martinfowler.com/books/eaa.html) book invaluable in learning how to write my own UoW, DataMappers and Repositories, all based on ADO.Net. It's written by someone who's obviously done it for real, made all the mistakes and then documented them so that you don't have to. I haven't read the article you've linked, however I'm often wary of using articles like this as they only demonstrate a surface-level consideration of patterns like this.

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I wrote a [blog post](http://blog.sapiensworks.com/post/2014/06/04/Unit-Of-Work-is-the-new-Singleton.aspx) why that very tutorial you've linked is harmful . tldr; a repository uses a DAO implementing UoW, but the repository should not be part of a  UoW. Unless you like to complicate your code base/life.

To answer your questions:

1. Once you're using EF or any other ORM, UoW is automatically implemented there. If you go the micro-ORM path (there is no valid reason to use ado.net directly) , the UoW is basically the db transaction. A repository should always deal with application objects, **never** with ORM (persistence) objects. If your app objects are used as persistence entities, then you probably have a standard CRUD app, and you don't really need the repository pattern. For simple apps, use the ORM directly (it saves a lot of time).
2. A Repository makes use of a DAO implementing UoW as an implementation detail. The rest of the app isn't aware of anything outside the repository (interface) itself.
3. A repository interface is defined where it's used (usually a the Domain/Business layer). The repository  **implementation** is part of the DAL. Note that you should use repositories **only** for changing the model (create/update/delete). For queries, it's much easier and maintainable to have [query services (objects)](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2013/10/29/put-your-controllers-on-a-diet-gets-and-queries/) handling a specific use cases and which work with the db directly.

There's a a LOT of misusing the repository pattern out there, I suggest reading my ["Repository for dummies"](http://blog.sapiensworks.com/post/2014/06/02/The-Repository-Pattern-For-Dummies.aspx) post to understand that's a very simple pattern which has nothing to do with the complicated examples you're usually seeing.

Comment: I liked your blog post in the way you explained it from the perspective of the business or domain layer, however, one thing got me confused. When you said:  "That's why all the repository interfaces reside in the Business layer, while their concrete implementation is part of the Persistence Layer (DAL).", were you talking about the Business and DAL in the same project or different projects? If different projects then won't that create a circular reference? because the concrete implementations in DAL layer need to reference the Business layer for the interfaces..

Comment: ...and the Business layer will need to reference the DAL layer for the concrete implementations of the interfaces it has.

Comment: @user20358 It doesn't matter. The 'layer' is just a logical context. The point is the repo implementation sits in another context than the domain, basically part of the infrastructure.

Comment: @MikeSW The "blog link" is not found.

Comment: @vivek Thanks, I fixed it now.